# UVa online judge - 3n + 1 - wrong answer?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here's my C++ code for [the 3n+1 problem from UVA online judge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) which runs fine here, but each submission is judged as the wrong solution. I believe it has something to do with input, or output formatting. I just don't know exactly what the issue is. Could anyone help me investigate this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, j, ori, orj, complexity = 0;
    while(!cin.eof()){
      cin >> i >> j;
      ori = i;
      orj = j;
      if (i > j){
          int temp = i;
          i = j; 
          j = temp;
      }

    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++){
        int c = 1;
        int n = k;
        do{
            c++;
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                n /= 2;
            else
                n = 3 * n + 1;
        } while (n != 1);
        if (c > complexity)
            complexity = c;
      }
      cout << ori << " " << orj << " " << complexity << endl;
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Each submission has come under the time limit, and when I debug i get correct outputs.

Comment: I got a wrong output for the sample input. https://ideone.com/lAJDtV

Comment: "when I debug i get correct outputs." Really? How on earth did you debug without the sample input? Or does it mean you didn't do any debug?

Answer (score 0):

`!cin.eof()` is not a good way to determine when to exit from the loop.

Try changing

```
while(!cin.eof()){
  cin >> i >> j;
```

to

```
while(cin >> i >> j){
```

Comment: It's just code enhancement, it doesn't fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear value of complexity variable for every new input numbers. Your code also doesn't handles correctly values of i and j equal to 1. You have to add special condition and not to run the loop in this case. So this it the whole code change:

```
int main() {
    int i, j, ori, orj, complexity;
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        complexity = 0;
        cin >> i >> j;
        ori = i;
        orj = j;
        if (i > j) {
            int temp = i;
            i = j;
            j = temp;
        }

        if (j > 1) {
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                int c = 1;
                int n = k;
                do {
                    c++;
                    if (n % 2 == 0)
                        n /= 2;
                    else
                        n = 3 * n + 1;
                } while (n != 1);
                if (c > complexity)
                    complexity = c;
            }
        } else {
            complexity = 1;
        }
        cout << ori << " " << orj << " " << complexity << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong? It's correct output as https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36 stays.

Comment: Just as wrote in my answer: `!cin.eof()` is not a good condition.